# problem in installing ImageMagick on centos7

Tags: installation, imagemagick, centos7

I'm trying to install ImageMagick-c++-devel using "yum install ImageMagick-c++-devel"
but this error occurs:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libgs.so.9 from install of libgs-9.25-2.el7_7.3.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ghostscript-9.07-28.el7_4.2.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libijs-0.35.so from install of libgs-9.25-2.el7_7.3.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ghostscript-9.07-28.el7_4.2.x86_64
```

---

Even when I removed libijs-0.35.so file, this error repeated again.
Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4):

Just delete the package of this document conversion

```
yum remove ghostscript-fonts-5.50-32.el7.noarch
```